# I need help to finish installing the latest version of Chromium

Tags: chromium

I am trying to install Chromium 48 on my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. I have already gotten all of the necessary files downloaded and expanded using these commands:

```
mkdir Chromium
cd Chromium/
wget https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Arm/103408/chrome-linux.zip
unzip chrome-linux.zip
```

After that finished running I used this command:

```
./chrome-linux/chrome
```

But I got this error:

```
./chrome-linux/chrome: symbol lookup error: /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so: undefined symbol: glPointSizePointerOES
```

I have been trying to resolve the issue myself but I am new to Raspberry Pi so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I should also mention I already had a version of Chromium installed so I had all the other packages and libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? If so which one?

Comment: It looks as though you are missing a library so `ldd ./chrome-linux/chrome` may help you to identify what is missing...

Comment: I have used multiple sources to get to where I am. I got Chromium in the first place from (http://conoroneill.net/running-the-latest-chromium-45-on-debian-jessie-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/). Its definately unzipped. I tried "ldd ./chrome-linux/chrome" and it returned "not a dynamic executable"

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you are using outdated instructions.
Chromium is now in the apt-get repositories.
All you need to do is this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

If you're asked "Do you want to continue?" or something like that, hit "y" then Enter and your Pi will download and install Chromium and its requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you're using an unsupported version of that library.

Here are some points:

- You may have to recompile.

  - Chromium requires at least version 2.15 of the `libc6` library. This can be found on Raspbian Jessie. Compiling on Wheezy would be problematic.
  - I think you also have to link `libGLESv2.so` and maybe `libOpenVG.so`. Mess around with the Makefile if you're recompiling.
- Do not use any mesa-based graphics library!
- Maybe consider Iceweasel?

Answer (score 0):

Running the following commands should work if you are on the newest version of Raspbian, which is Raspbian Jessie.

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87113035/chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i chromium-browser-l10n_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_all.deb chromium-browser_48.0.2564.82-0ubuntu0.15.04.1.1193_armhf.deb
```

This worked for me with no problems.